# How to open ESLint warning paths in WebStorm?

Tags: eslint, webstorm

The picture shows a few warnings created by the ESLint in WebStorm terminal. How can I make those paths clickable?

[image]

Comment: looks similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-54562, please follow it for updates

Comment: Ok I upvoted the issue there. Still looking for a workaround solution.

Comment: there are no workarounds unfortunately